# Upper bound on number of edges for graph with no C3 or C4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, extremal-graph-theory

> $G$ is a simple graph having $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Show that if G has girth $\ge$ 5, then $$m \le \frac12 n \sqrt{n-1}$$.

***I am required to use a particular method: i.e. show first that $\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w) \le n-1$, N(v) being the neighbor of any vertex in $G$. Then use this fact and $(\sum_{w} d(w))^2 \le n*\sum_{w} d(w)^2$ by cauchy's thm to show the result.

I got the first part but I am having trouble showing the second part using its result.

My thinking is as follows: $\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w) \le n-1$ implies $\sum_{v \in G} \sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w) \le n*(n-1)$, since $\sum_{v \in G}$ means counting n times. We also have $\sum_{x\in v} d(x)=2m$ so $(\sum_{x\in v} d(x))^2=4m^2$.

Cauchy Schwarz gets. $(\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w))^2 \le n*\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w)^2$

I am kind of stuck here and don't really know how to use the above things I derived to get the result. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hint:
$$\sum_{v \in G} \sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w) = \sum_{v \in G} d(v)^2.$$

Comment: this only gives $2m \le n(n-1)$ not a good enough upper bound i think?

i need something for the left side of$(\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w))^2$ like $ ... \le (\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w))^2$ to find the result i believe

Comment: @JosephCamacho or am i using your hint wrong?

Comment: That's the basic idea.  However, you might be using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality wrong.  You should have
$$\left(\sum_{v \in G} d(v)\right)^2 \le n\sum_{v \in G} d(v)^2 = n\sum_{v \in G} \sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w) \le n \sum_{v \in G} (n - 1) = n^2(n - 1).$$

Comment: @JosephCamacho thank you, I see that does make sense thank you--however, i actually need to use $(\sum_{w} d(w))^2 \le n*\sum_{w} d(w)^2$ as part of the instructions (just edited now sorry), is there any way i can use $(\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w))^2 \le n*\sum_{w \in N(v)} d(w)^2$ to show the result as well?

Comment: Look at the first inequality I wrote...